# Got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject

Tags: java, groovy

Got the following exception while executing a java class in a command shelll

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObj
ect
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Because the code is not written by me, and I am not familiar with groovy, it's difficult to me to investigate where the issue is. Please kindly give me a clue.

PS:I have added groovy-all.jar to my classpath.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError means that the Class definition was present during compile time, but is not available in your runtime. can you check the run classpath to make the sure that the appropriate jar is included.

Comment: Please show how you're invoking the class and where did you place groovy-all.jar.

Comment: @Strelok For example: java -classpath D:\test\groovy-all.jar com.mypackage.Test,     As I mentioned the class is not written by me,and it's quite complicated. It's not easy to give the invoking point.

Comment: the reason I asked, is because placing `groovy-all.jar` on the class path should be enough. If it's not working then the devil in this case is in the detail. So everything is important. How exactly you're invoking the class. Your exact classpath, etc.

Comment: which version of groovy are u using?

Comment: @Byter From groovy-all.jar, I found a property file: groovy-release-info.properties, one property is ImplementationVersion=1.8.3

Answer (score 3):

An issue I ran into was a version mismatch of Groovy. More specifically, it seemed that I was running a compiled groovy class under 2.1.1 where it was compiled under 1.8.6

Changing the library included on the classpath to 1.8.6 resolved my issue.