# Groovy Servlet met java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject

Tags: servlets, groovy

I'm trying to build a very simple Servlet using Groovy. Since it's just a single servlet plus a couple of gsp pages I don't want to integrate Grails into my project because I'm new to it. When I want the servlet run on Tomcat server(v7.0) I met such exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)...
```

Look at this thread [Got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858339/got-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-groovy-lang-groovyobject) It seems the servlet.groovy is compiled fine but runtime env is not met.
My question is, how can I meet the runtime env without Grails(if possible)? I already have groovy-all-2.3.7.jar in my buildpath. Or could it be caused by version problems?

The servlet is extremely simple because I met the problem at very beginning.

```
import groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet

class Dispatcher extends GroovyServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Dispatcher(){
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        println request;
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        println(request.getParameter("option"));
        request.setAttribute("option", request.getParameter("option"));
        Map<String,Object> result=new HashMap<>();
        request.setAttribute("result", result);
        println request;
        // Forward to GSP file to display message
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("/result.gsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Comment: You write _ I already have groovy-all-2.3.7.jar in my buildpath_, but do you have it in your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib`, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder?

Comment: Oops it was not included in Tomcat's lib folder. Now it works perfectly. Thanks! I hope I knew it an hour ago!

Comment: @JozefChocholacek you should post that as an answer

Comment: @WillP OK, done. (I thought it's too trivial. :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the `groovy-all-2.3.7.jar` in the build path is not enough, it has to be in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp, or in the Tomcat's `lib` folder, too.